# Json decoding into struct, using different request type depending on path

Tags: go

I want to decode json to struct. My structs look like that:

```
type message struct {
 Request baseRequest `json:"request"`  //actually there should be other type here, but I can't think of what it could be
 Auth auth           `json:"auth"`
}

type baseRequest struct {
  Foo string `json:"foo" validate:"required"`
}

type createRequest struct {
  baseRequest
  Bar string `json:"bar" validate:"required"`
}

type cancelRequest struct{
  baseRequest
  FooBar string `json:"foo_bar" validate:"required"`
}
```

I want to compose `createRequest` with `baseRequest`. All my code is revolving around passing `message` type in chain of responsibility pattern. I have implemented a handler, that creates a pointer to empty `message` struct, that is used by `jsonReader()` function. For `/create` path I want to use `createRequest` instead of `baseRequest`, and for `/cancel` path I want to use `cancelRequest`. So for example in:

```
func (factory *HandlerFactory) Create() http.Handler {
    create := func() *message { return &message{} }
    return factory.defaultChain(createNewMessage, nil)
}
```

I want to change the type of message.Request() to `createRequest`.
And in:

```
func (factory *HandlerFactory) Cancel() http.Handler {
    create := func() *message { return &message{} }
    return factory.defaultChain(createNewMessage, nil)
}
```

I want to change the type of message.Request to `cancelRequest`. How can I achieve something like that in Go?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately what you are trying to do is not really how Go works, since Go does not have polymorphism - createRequest and cancelRequest do not inherit from baseRequest, they *contain* a baseRequest. So when you have baseRequest in your message struct, it can't be anything other than a baseRequest.

You may need to use separate types for each message. One for the cancel request, and a different one for the create request.

Here is [an article](http://hackthology.com/object-oriented-inheritance-in-go.html) discussing inheritance and composition in Go, and contrasts it with Java. It should help you grok how struct embedding works in Go.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found the way. You could implement message like this:

```
type message struct {
  Request request `json:"request"`  //actually there should be other type here, but I can't think of what it could be
  Auth auth           `json:"auth"`
}
```

Where `request` is an interface, which has `serialize()`

```
type request interface {
    serialize() ([]byte, error)
}
```

Then you can implement `serialize()` for every request type, and initialize `message` like this:

```
func (factory *HandlerFactory) Cancel() http.Handler {
    create := func() *message { return &message{&cancelRequest{}, auth{}} }
    return factory.defaultChain(createNewMessage, nil)
}
```